# Issue while trying to find the unique number of a list

Tags: python, arrays

I'm working on an exercise where I have to find the unique number of a list the fastest way. The list will have at least 3 numbers and will be composed by only 2 different numbers not more and it has to be fast enough to avoid the times out.
Moreover, I have to return the result as a number not as a list, I tried to use
`''.join(map(str, my_list))` but the test aren't good on it because it convert the value of the list as a string.
I've made this code:

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    my_list = []
    prev = ""
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        prev = arr[0]
        if prev != arr[i]:
            return arr[i]
```

When I executed the test on it, every test worked perfectly but there's one that crashed every time. It's the case when the unique number is in `arr[0]`.

I know there is code on stackoverflow for this exercise, but I would like to solve it without looking at an explicit solution.

I don't know what condition to add to avoid this problem please.

I passed the test in those case:

```
find_uniq([ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ])
find_uniq([ 0, 0, 0.55, 0, 0 ])
find_uniq([ 3, 10, 3, 3, 3 ])
```

But for example, I fail this one:

```
find_uniq([ 10, 3, 3, 3, 3 ])
```

I got `3` in return value.

Comment: don't know why you are using range here

Comment: So all the numbers except the unique one are defined to be the same? In your program you are not searching for a unique number at all.

Comment: you doesn't search unique but first which is different then `arr[0]`

Comment: you would count items on list and get this item which is only once on list.

Comment: Unless your list is sorted, merely comparing an item with neighboring items is not sufficient. You need to rethink your basic logic *before* you plunge into coding. As a hint, why not create a dictionary of counts? (doing it with raw Python is easy enough, but you could also use `collections.Counter`)

Comment: What your current code does is merely return the first item that differs from the previous one. It should be obvious why this fails for something like `[3,4,3,4,5]`

Comment: @CodeIt That would work (but is needlessly quadratic in complexity) -- but why not respect OP's desire to figure it out themselves (with perhaps a hint)?

Comment: @JohnColeman it's what I'm looking for, because in this exercise the list are only composed by the same number repeat different type and only one different number so the `[3,4,3,4,5]` is not acceptable in this case.

Comment: 1) It doesn't hurt to put constraints like that in the question rather than the comments 2) it doesn't hurt to write a more generally useful function, and 3) it still fails for `[10,3,3,3,]` since the first thing that differs from its predecessor isn't the unique thing.

Comment: @JohnColeman Removed my comment.

Comment: @AndrejKesely the list will have at least 3 numbers

Comment: if your list may have only two values repreated in different order then count them and when one value has two items then other value is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed that unique number is not first element of list. By comparing other element by first element of list you are limited to this and your code does not work on

```
find_uniq([ 10, 3, 3, 3, 3 ])
```

For have a complete solution, as you have at least 3 elements in list,

```py
def find_uniq(arr):
    count_first=0
    count_second=0
    first=arr[0]
    second=nan
    i=1
    while(i<len(arr)):
        if(arr[i]!=first):
            second=arr[i]
            count_second+=1
            if(count_second>1):
                return first;
        else:
            count_first+=1
            if(count_first>1):
                return second;
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the question: *...The list will have at least 3 numbers and will be composed by only 2 different numbers...*:

```
l = [10,3,3,3]

for v1, v2, v3 in zip(l, l[1:], l[2:]):
    if v1 == v2 == v3:
        continue
    elif v1 != v2 == v3:
        print(v1)
        break
    elif v1 != v2 != v3:
        print(v2)
        break
    elif v1 == v2 != v3:
        print(v3)
        break
```

Will print:

```
10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    my_list = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr.count(arr[i])==1:
            my_list.append(arr[i])
    return my_list
```

Try this hopefully this will work as you want this function return list of number that are unique in given list

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter


def find_unique(arr):
    return Counter(arr).most_common()[-1][0]
```

`most_common` will return a list of two 2-tuples, each consisting of an element and the number of times it appears. The unique element will, by definition, be the least common element and appear at the end of the list.

For example, `Counter([ 0, 0, 0.55, 0, 0 ]).most_common()` returns `[(0, 4), (0.55, 1)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
def find_uniq(arr):
    return [el for el in set(arr) if arr.count(el)==1]
```

Comment: `list(set(arr))` is not needed, just use `set(arr)`. Between OP expects a number not a list.

Comment: You don't need to iterate over the values from the set since the OP has mentioned that the list will only contain two numbers. `def find_uniq(arr): x,y = set(arr); return (x if arr.count(x) == 1 else y)`

Comment: `set(arr)` would always return the two distinct values from the list.